# Can't install MuMIn package in R

Tags: r, package, install.packages, mumin

I have come back to some old code from last year and I can't seem to install the MuMIn package. It keeps coming up with this error

`install.packages("MuMIn")`

```
Warning in install.packages : package ‘MuMIn’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

All my other packages are downloading. Not sure what to do? I have R version 4.1.1

EDIT

I have found code to download previous version of MuMIn package but I get this error.

```
> packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MuMIn/MuMIn_1.43.15.tar.gz"
> install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘C:/****/****/****/****/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in download.file(p, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  'wget' call had nonzero exit status
```

(Have put ** to hide computer pathway)

Thanks.

Comment: you need quotes e.g. `install.packages("MuMIn")`

Comment: @user20650 I know silly me I realised that but then came up with another error message.

Comment: your second attempt works for me, I suspect that you have some kind of network/firewall problem.  Can you download the tarball manually and use `install.packages(<local_filename>, repos = NULL, type = "source')` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for your help Ben but I think my companies firewall is blocking me from doing this. I have found another package that was able to download and had the function I wanted

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [package's CRAN page](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=MuMIn) you'll see  that it lists

> Depends:  R (≥ 4.2.0)

which is greater than your current version.

You can update your R version, **or** go back in the archives to install an older version without this dependency, e.g. `remotes::install_version("MuMIn", "1.46.0")`

Comment: As I use R with my company, they have (annoyingly) cracked down on the security issues it faces and won't let us use any other version of R apart from 4.1.1.

Comment: Fair enough. Does this answer solve your problem, though? (It *doesn't* require a later version of R, just offers that as an alternative.)